# Will I lose all mining time if I restart my miner?

Tags: mining, mining-pools, ethminer, solo-mining

An example about solo mining with my own pool:

When I stop the miner after about 3 days and start it again, is the mining time lost to find a block?

Answer (score 3):

Mining isn't like, well, actual mining, it's more like flipping a coin; each attempt at finding a block is independent of the previous one. As a result, there's no 'progress' to be lost by restarting.

Comment: What about if you're not solo mining, but rather are pool mining?  And the pool pays a % based on the share of work your miner performs on a block. I think this is a common scenario.  If I restart my miner, do I lose the work share that I have contributed to the block?