# Geth says it's synced, but is about 50 blocks behind everyone else

Tags: go-ethereum, cpp-ethereum

So I run a small eth mining pool and the eth node says it's synced, but when I compare the block to the ones on other pools we are about 50-100 blocks behind.  When I check in geth it says it's fully synced.

I recently did a re-sync because the blockchain was getting much too large, but it kept locking up and causing me to have to start the sync again.

I did just setup an etc node and synced it, but in doing so I think it may have changed my geth version to a much older one.  I updated it but still having the issues.  I would hate to have to delete the chaindata and sync again as my miners would be really upset at loosing their progress on the current block, but also being so many blocks behind we will either never find a block or get an orphan.  Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

Re: lost "progress": see [Will I lose all mining time if I restart my miner?](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/3639/will-i-lose-all-mining-time-if-i-restart-my-miner/3654#3654)

I don't have any suggestions about speeding up syncing or catching up. However, to avoid downtime, you can run a second node (virtualizing, separate data directory, separate machine, take your pick) and use port-forwarding to switch between the two nodes. This gives you almost instant switching between the chains. If your mining pool software supports failover, I think `geth` will reject work requests until it thinks it is synced. To be sure, you can start it with its RPC port closed until it's caught up and restart geth with the port open. You might have a bit of wasted mining on a slightly-outdated blockchain, but you should be caught up in a few seconds if your node is moderately specced for a desktop computer.